# How to dynamically import a module in lwc

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, es6

I am trying to import modules dynamically in my LWC component.

While pushing the change I get a strange error `LWC1509: This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'dynamicImport'`

**Here is sample code that produces the error**

*calculator/calculator.js*

```
export default class Calculator {
    static add = (a, b) =>  a + b;
}
```

*sample/sample.js*

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
// import Calculator from "c/calculator";

export default class Sample extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        import("c/calculator")
        .then(Calculator => alert(Calculator.add(1, 2)))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

I could't find any documentation which mentions [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) is not supported in LWC.

Google redirects me to a [github issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10345) raised for babel. Is this a limitation with LWC or am I missing something?

Comment: I think dynamic imports are used only for dynamic instantiation of components. See [this RFC](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc-rfcs/pull/10). I've used the `lwc:dynamic` syntax in LWC OSS projects and as far as I know it's not yet available inside of Salesforce.

I think you are getting an error meant to show only in LWC OSS.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try

```
export Calculator {
    static add = (a, b) =>  a + b;
}
```

without the default/class keyword. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a LWC only with the XML by default and the JS.

In the JS you export what you want, for example:

```
export function getQueryParameters() {
...
}
export function whateverFunction(){
...
}
```

this LWC is called jsUtilities, and the code only has this functions.

Then, when you want to import, you have to use the syntax like this:

```
import { getQueryParameters, whateverFunction } from 'c/jsUtilities';
```

And to use it just don't use this.getQueryParameters() but just the name of the function:

```
renderedCallback(){
        if(!this.initialized){
            let urlParams = getQueryParameters();
...
```